# How to create a custom video palyer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I need to create the following video player for my app: [Screenshot from Netflix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSip.png). I need a start/pause button, a back button, the title of the video, and a time indicator. The video should also always be in landscape mode. I've already found a lot of video players in flutter but I haven't found a way to modify them. If anybody knows a good library, a tutorial, or has some source code it would really help me out, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package, as it's the most bare-bones package out there. You can make the player all to your liking by using the `Stack` Widget, having the video at its base and any other elements on top of it. It should be very doable; only the progress indicator is kind of complex, but it's not too bad.